# How do I get all the rows from a mysql table, send json, iterate through array and display?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I have this PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT banner FROM banners ") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $somethings = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $somethings[] = $row;
}

  print json_encode($somethings);   exit;
```

which gives me this json response:

```
[{"name":"john"},{"name":"Peter"}]
```

and I have this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function getdata(data) {
$.each($data, function(key, value) {jQuery('#boxes').append('==='+value); }); 
}
$.getJSON('editx2.php',{ 'case':9,'readonly': 'yes' }, getdata);    
});
```

which dispays this:

```
[object Object],[object Object][object Object],[object Object]
```

I have two rows in the database. When the array is in this format:

```
{"name":"john","name":"peter"}
```

it works, but this fails:

```
[{"name":"john"},{"name":"Peter"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
jQuery('#boxes').append('==='+value);
```

use

```
jQuery('#boxes').append('==='+value.name);
```

which will print the name.